# Função JavaScript só está funcionando com 1 ou 2 variáveis

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a seguinte código para verificar se um *radio* está selecionado, se estiver, executar tal função:

```html
<script language="javascript">
  document.onclick = function setFries() {
    var apc = document.getElementById("10000_3").checked;
    var ape = document.getElementById("10000_5").checked;

    if (apc) {
      window.alert("teste 1");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Porém se eu adiciono mais de 2 variáveis o script simplesmente não funciona.

No total utilizarei 24 variáveis, então fiz da seguinte maneira:

```html
<script language="javascript">
  document.onclick = function setFries() {
    var apc = document.getElementById("10000_3").checked;
    var ape = document.getElementById("10000_5").checked;
    var aac = document.getElementById("10000_6").checked;
    var aae = document.getElementById("10000_7").checked;
    var cpc = document.getElementById("10000_8").checked;
    var cpe = document.getElementById("10000_9").checked;
    var cac = document.getElementById("10000_10").checked;
    var cae = document.getElementById("10000_11").checked;
    var dpc = document.getElementById("10000_12").checked;
    var dpe = document.getElementById("10000_13").checked;
    var dac = document.getElementById("10000_14").checked;
    var dae = document.getElementById("10000_15").checked;
    var hpc = document.getElementById("10000_16").checked;
    var hpe = document.getElementById("10000_17").checked;
    var hac = document.getElementById("10000_18").checked;
    var hae = document.getElementById("10000_19").checked;
    var lpc = document.getElementById("10000_20").checked;
    var lpe = document.getElementById("10000_21").checked;
    var lac = document.getElementById("10000_22").checked;
    var lae = document.getElementById("10000_23").checked;
    var ppc = document.getElementById("10000_24").checked;
    var ppe = document.getElementById("10000_25").checked;
    var pac = document.getElementById("10000_26").checked;
    var pae = document.getElementById("10000_27").checked;

    if (apc) {
      window.alert("teste 2");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Porém não funcionou, fui excluindo de 1 em 1 variável, e só deu certo quando tinha 2.

Por gentileza, onde está o erro?

Comment: Esses elementos de HTML existem? Podes explicar o que estás a tentar fazer? Escrever isso tudo à mão parece-me má ideia... Acho que dá para optimizar muito.

Comment: De onde vem a variável a3 no primeiro trecho de código? Que tal rodar a função setFries dentro do evento click.

Comment: Wesley, como o @Sergio apontou, me parece que você teve muito esforço para fazer algo simples, dê uma olhadinha no seguinte fiddle.: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dkenu99/)

Comment: @Maurivan obrigado pela observação, esqueci de altera-la em quanto escrevia a pergunta aqui no site, seria 'apc'

Comment: @Sergio obrigado pela observação, estava trabalhando com referências inexistentes, estou reajustando para ver se o problema era apenas este.

Comment: @Tobias podemos mover para um chat por gentileza? não sei se devo ficar comentando ou editando a pergunta. ps: não sei como faço para mover para um chat

Comment: @Wesley ainda não explicaste o que queres fazer...

Comment: @Sergio olá Sergio, passei para o Fiddle para exemplificar melhor minha necessidade https://jsfiddle.net/h3hkduym/6/
São 12 formulários na mesma página, cada um deles possuem 2 input do tipo radio para usuário escolher uma ou outra opção.
A função chamada por onclick no botão submit deverá exibir um alerta para o usuário (de acordo com a seleção será um alert diferente).
O que não consegui fazer: que a função limpe a seleção do usuário nos outros formulários, pois cada um possui 2 opções de seleção e 1 botão submit. Exemplo, form 1, selecionado 1º radio, ao submeter resetar demais seleções.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita Tobias, é possível modificar seu código para que ao clicar em um radio, os outros sejam desselecionados? https://jsfiddle.net/6dkenu99/4/ da forma que fiz, não é possível escolher os radios do form 2 nem 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei reproduzir o seu cenário atual me baseando no seu exemplo postado nos comentários.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
    return value + 1;
});
var data = [
  [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], 
  [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], 
  [20, 21], [22, 23], [24, 25], [26, 27]
];
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var source = document.getElementById("tmpl").textContent;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
form.innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>
<form id="form">

</form>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Form {{inc @index}}
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[0]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[0]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[0]}}" name="options_{{inc @index}}" data-color="black" />
    Black
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[1]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[1]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[1]}}" name="options_{{inc @index}}" data-color="blue" />
    Blue
  </label>
</fieldset>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Primeiro você precisa entender como o `input[type='radio']` funciona, ele vai manter um único `input` selecionado dentre todos com o mesmo `name`.

No exemplo acima, o `Form 1` tem `inputs` com o `name` `options_1`, o `Form 2` com `options_2` e assim por diante, por isto ao selecionar uma opção em um `Form` os demais não são deselecionados.

agora veja o que acontece quando todos os `inputs` tem o mesmo `name`.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
    return value + 1;
});
var data = [
  [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], 
  [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], 
  [20, 21], [22, 23], [24, 25], [26, 27]
];
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var source = document.getElementById("tmpl").textContent;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
form.innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>
<form id="form">

</form>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Form {{inc @index}}
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[0]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[0]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[0]}}" name="options" data-color="black" />
    Black
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[1]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[1]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[1]}}" name="options" data-color="blue" />
    Blue
  </label>
</fieldset>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Mas se por algum motivo, você precisa que os inputs em forms distintos precisem ter `name` distintos, então você pode usar a versão à seguir.:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options) {
    return value + 1;
});
var data = [
  [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], 
  [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], 
  [20, 21], [22, 23], [24, 25], [26, 27]
];
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var source = document.getElementById("tmpl").textContent;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
form.innerHTML = template(data);

(function () {
  var options = form.querySelectorAll("input[name^='options']");
  var current = null;
  var onOptionClick = function (event) {
    var proposto = event.target;
    if (current && current.name != proposto.name) {
      current.checked = false;
    }
    current = proposto;
  };
  [].forEach.call(options, function (option, indice) {
    option.addEventListener("click", onOptionClick);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>
<form id="form">

</form>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Form {{inc @index}}
  </legend>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[0]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[0]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[0]}}" name="options_{{inc @index}}" data-color="black" />
    Black
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  id="10000_{{this.[1]}}" type="radio" class="poll_answer {{this.[1]}} twoglux_styled" value="{{this.[1]}}" name="options_{{inc @index}}" data-color="blue" />
    Blue
  </label>
</fieldset>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado! Usei o terceiro exemplo, pois preciso do 'name' diferente para cada formulário.